# Any idea why the lighting is bugging out on the left, i found this out when i was rendering my scene to see how it looked

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I was rendering my scene early to see how it looks and i ran into the lighting or something getting bugged out when i was rendering. Im using cycles and any idea on how to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks a bunch[image]!

Comment: You're going to have to clarify this.. it look reasonable from the evidence, on the left. Do you mean the triangles on the right?

Answer (score 0):

there may be multiple objects in the same area. try clicking on the bugged out area and deleting some things.